# echo product selected quantity woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I want to display added product quantity in cart in single product page as text [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vY17o.png)

This is currently what i'm using in functions.php, I want to display the quantity number between.

```
add_action('woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_form', 'gripsquantity', 5);
function gripsquantity(){ 
    echo 'Choose ';
    echo 'Grips';
}
```

Thank you

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: this is not a valid code for me. what is `add`?

Comment: Sorry, I fixed the code now

Answer (score 0):

Get cart object

```
$items = WC()->cart->get_cart();
```

Loop through cart items

```
foreach( $items as $item => $values ) {   
    if( $values ['product_id'] === $yourProductId ){
        // Get product qty in cart
        $quantity_in_cart = $values['quantity'];
    }   
}
```

Comment: It didn't work also.. I added it to functions.php but it didn't show anything in frontend